# Error : type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Ad1'

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't manage an issue with `"type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Ad1'`. I'll appreciate your help, please.

I'm using Firestore and my data are like this:

```
  {
    "name": "toto@ttt.fr",
    "nom": "ducat",
    "prenom": "raoul",
    "profilcomplete": 0,
    "compteur": 0,
    "cercle": 10,
    "ad1": {
        "adresse": "gnagna",
        "cp": "75013",
        "ville": "paris",
        "position":[82.3,2.37]
    }
}
```

My model class (AppUserData.dart) is:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

AppUserData appUserDataFromMap(String str) =>
    AppUserData.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String appUserDataToMap(AppUserData data) => json.encode(data.toMap());
class AppUserData {
  AppUserData({
    required this.uid,
    required this.name,
    required this.nom,
    required this.prenom,
    required this.profilcomplete,
    required this.compteur,
    required this.cercle,
    required this.ad1,
  });

  String uid;
  String name;
  String nom;
  String prenom;
  bool profilcomplete;
  int compteur;
  int cercle;
  Ad1 ad1;

  factory AppUserData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AppUserData(
        uid: json["uid"],
        name: json["name"],
        nom: json["nom"],
        prenom: json["prenom"],
        profilcomplete: json["profilcomplete"],
        compteur: json["compteur"],
        cercle: json["cercle"],
        ad1: Ad1.fromMap(json["ad1"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "name": name,
        "nom": nom,
        "prenom": prenom,
        "profilcomplete": profilcomplete,
        "compteur": compteur,
        "cercle": cercle,
        "ad1": ad1.toMap(),
      };
}

class Ad1 {
  Ad1({
    required this.adresse,
    required this.cp,
    required this.ville,
    required this.position,
  });

  String adresse;
  String cp;
  String ville;
  GeoPoint position;

  factory Ad1.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ad1(
        adresse: json["adresse"],
        cp: json["cp"],
        ville: json["ville"],
        position: json["position"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "adresse": adresse,
        "cp": cp,
        "ville": ville,
        "position": position,
      };
}
```

I'm using a file called database.dart to access and write [EDIT WITH SOLUTION]:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:ttt/models/user.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService(this.uid);

  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> userCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");
  AppUserData _userFromSnapshot(
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.data();
    if (data == null) throw Exception("Utilisateur non trouvé");
    print(snapshot.id);
    return AppUserData(
      uid: snapshot.id,
      name: data['name'],
      nom: data['nom'],
      prenom: data['prenom'],
      compteur: data['compteur'],
      profilcomplete: data['profilcomplete'],
      // ad1: data['ad1'],  <-- doesn't work
      ad1: Ad1.fromMap(data["ad1"]), // <-- Solution (Thanks daddygames)
      cercle: data['cercle'],
    );
  }

Stream<AppUserData> get user {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userFromSnapshot);
  }

List<AppUserData> _userListFromSnapshot(
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return _userFromSnapshot(doc);
    }).toList();
  }

 Stream<List<AppUserData>> get users {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .orderBy('ad1.position')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

And when I want to display a list by using `StreamProvider<List<AppUserData>>`, I have this error:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Ad1'
```

What did I miss or done wrong? Thanks

Comment: It's when you're instantiating your `AppUserData` object. You're assigning `data['ad1']` to your ad1 property. You should use `Ad1.fromMap(data["ad1"])` or `AppUserData.fromMap(data)`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !!! I was very far from this solution. I was looking at the model class... It works fine now.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that worked. I made my comment an answer in case you would like to mark it as the answer. Let me know if you'd like more details added to the answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's when you're instantiating your `AppUserData` object. You're assigning `data['ad1']` to your `ad1` property. You should use `Ad1.fromMap(data["ad1"])` or `AppUserData.fromMap(data)`